# Comma before conjuctions in predicates containing two coordinate clauses

Tags: oxford-comma, compound-sentences, coordinating-conjunctions

I know that a comma is necessary before a conjunction joining two independent clauses, like in the following examples:

> John is tall, **and** Mary is fast.
>
> The food is excellent, **but** the service is awful.

But what happens when there is a subordinate clause formed in turn by two independent clauses connected by a coordinating conjunction? Should there be a comma before the conjunction? I am referring to
sentences like these:

> She says that John is tall **and** Mary is fast.
>
> I hate those restaurants where the food is excellent **but** the service is awful.
>
> I am leaving the country so that the police cannot find me **and** I don't go to jail.

I tend to think there should be no comma in this kind of sentences, but I would appreciate if someone could confirm it. Assuming I am right, is that true independently of the length of the coordinate clauses?

Answer (score 2):

Your instincts seem correct. The clauses that are independent in your first example are treated in the subsequent examples not as clauses, but as objects in a series.

> She says [what]
>
> She says A [John is tall] and B [Mary is fast]

The second example is even more clear. The type of restaurants that are hated must meet two criteria: excellent food AND awful service. The items are not really independent, even if they are expressed in separate clauses.

Note that treating these clauses as a series rather than as independent thoughts *would* lead to the use of commas if there were more than two concepts in the series

> She said that John is tall, Mary is fast, and Peter is charming.

This follows the common approach of not separating two items in a series with a comma but using commas when there are three or more items.